# Removing a substring from a string

Tags: java, string

I have a very simple question and just can't get my code to work in Java. I want to return a string that indicates a filepath, but extracts a certain portion of that path if it it exists.

So, my input might be "c:/lotus/notes/data/directory/mydatabase.nsf" and I want to return only "directory/mydatabase.nsf". Sometimes, the path provided will already leave out the "c:/lotus/notes/data/" because it is being accessed on the server rather than locally.

```
public String getDataPath ( String path ) {
    int pathStart;
    boolean pathContains;
    String lowerPath;

    lowerPath = path.toLowerCase();
    pathStart = lowerPath.indexOf("c:/lotus/notes/data");

    if ( pathStart >= 0) {
        // 20 characters in "c:/lotus/notes/data/"
        return path.substring(19);
    }

    pathContains = lowerPath.contains("lotus/notes/data");
    if ( pathContains ) {
        // 20 characters in "c:/lotus/notes/data/"
        return path.substring(19);
    }

    return path;
}
```

This is simple, but somehow, I can't get it right. Neither of my if's ever evaluates as true.

Comment: My problem turns out to have been the backslash "\". So, I needed to use path.replace("c:\\lotus\\notes\\data\\", ""); But the important thing is my multiple lines of clunky code that ALSO did not work got shortened down to one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
path.replace("c:/lotus/notes/data", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do a `path.replaceAll("c:/lotus/notes/data", "")`. This will remove the leading path name if it is contained in the string, else the string will not change.

Comment: This is not based off of a regular expression, so `.replace()` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Path` interface:

- [Paths Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)
- [Path Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

It is used to do exactly what you want: Extract informations about the single parts of a path.